# How to control runtime a new transaction using Spring JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, spring-jdbc, propagation

I'm using Spring JDBC with trx manager, usually I annotate the method with @Transaction like this:

```
   @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=Exception.class,  isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
      myTransactionalFunction(){
   }
```

But for a recursive operation I need to control the propagation, is there any way to remove the @Transactionl annotation and control it runtime with something like this:

```
myTransactionalFunction(boolean newTransaction){
    if(newTransaction)
        doSomethingLikeTransactionalPropagationRequiresNew();
    else
        doSomethingLikeTransactionalPropagationRequired();
}
```

I know it would be better to refactor the components structures, but in this particular case is it is more easy to control it runtime.

Comment: I will recommended to with programmatic way in such case to handle the transaction which give you more control. You can check that in spring docs

Comment: You can also go with @Conditional annotation . Just define one class which implement Conditional interface